# How to build project by Spring Boot + Mybatis + Mybatis Generator?

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I follow mybatis official website to build my project step by step, but it always can not work well, so I hope you could give me a fully guide from beginning to the end, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Step 1. Build a new spring boot project named booking.

This step is basically, I will skip it.

### Step 2. Add mybatis-generator to project.

This could help us to generate entity and mapper class mybatis needed automatically, it's very useful for us to save our time.

> 1. Add plugin config in pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

> 2. Create generatorConfig.xml at base resources path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd">

<generatorConfiguration>
    <context id="MySqlContext" targetRuntime="MyBatis3Simple" defaultModelType="flat">
        <jdbcConnection driverClass="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
                        connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/booking?useSSL=false"
                        userId="root"
                        password="123456">
            <property name="nullCatalogMeansCurrent" value="true" />
        </jdbcConnection>

        <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="com.clycle.booking.entity" targetProject="C:\Users\a243903\projects\booking\webapi\src\main\java">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true" />
            <property name="trimStrings" value="true" />
        </javaModelGenerator>

        <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="com.clycle.booking.mapper"  targetProject="C:\Users\a243903\projects\booking\webapi\src\main\resources">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true" />
        </sqlMapGenerator>

        <javaClientGenerator type="XMLMAPPER" targetPackage="com.clycle.booking.mapper"  targetProject="C:\Users\a243903\projects\booking\webapi\src\main\java">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true" />
        </javaClientGenerator>

        <table tableName="%">
        </table>

    </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

> 3. Create maven Run/Debug Configuration to run this plugin.

[image]

It will generate all entity, mapper class and mapper xml automatically. -Dmybatis.generator.overwrite=true, means it will overwrite existing entity or mapper class when run mybatis generator with maven.

### Step 3. Add mybatis to this project.

> 1. Add mybatis dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

> 2. Create mybatis-config.xml at base resources path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J" />
    </settings>

    <typeAliases>
        <package name="com.clycle.booking.entity" />
    </typeAliases>

    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC">
                <property name="" value="" />
            </transactionManager>
            <dataSource type="UNPOOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/booking" />
                <property name="username" value="root" />
                <property name="password" value="123456" />
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>

    <mappers>
        <package name="com.clycle.booking.mapper" />
        <!--<mapper resource="com/clycle/booking/mapper/ShopMapper.xml" />-->
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

> 3. Add @MapperScan for application main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan({"com.clycle.booking.mapper"})
public class BookingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookingApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> 4. Autowired mapper interface to operate your database.

```
@Autowired
private ShopMapper shopMapper;

@PostMapping(RoutePath.SHOP_LIST)
public List<Shop> GetList() {

    try {
        return shopMapper.selectAll();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download this project: https://github.com/yyqian/spring-boot-mybatis-generator .
Everything just work fine on my computer.

Comment: Hi Declan, welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to provide more verbose answers with the crucial parts of code in them (not externally linked). Also `Everything just work fine on my computer` isn't really helpful.